# /dev/ttyACM0 access denied on Lubuntu boot, but works any other time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to launch a program on Lubuntu 19.04 that talks to my Arduino Due device (robotics) via serial with /dev/ttyACM0. Everything seems fine, until I try to launch the app at startup.

The problem occurs only when I try to make my app boot at login. Running it as user, from terminal, from `.desktop` file, from script etc. is not a problem at all, I am able to establish connection 10/10 times.

Please bear in mind that I am putting `$USER` manually now, in every command it is explicitly passed as my de facto username.

It shouldn't be a permissions problem.

```
$ ls -la /dev/
...
crw-rw-rw-   1 root dialout 166,     0 mar 13 17:27 ttyACM0
...
```

```
$ groups $USER

$USER : $USER root adm tty dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

I have tried runing it from `.xsessionrc` with:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Some other commands to set the environment up

/home/$USER/user_panel /dev/ttyACM0
```

I have also tried setting it in LXQt Session Settings with Autostart so i ended up with a `.desktop` entry:

```
$ cat ./.config/autostart/$USER\ User\ Panel.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/home/$USER/user_panel /dev/ttyACM0
Name=User Panel
Type=Application
Version=1.0
```

I have tried launching both of that files manually and it was alright, the app started, the connection was made.

I have also tried making my udev rule.

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/50-myusb.rules 

KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", MODE="0666
```

Hence, my question is: what should I look for as the reason for this boot time denial?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the same problem but I was getting "access denied" when opening /dev/ttyACM0 during a hot-boot of the USB connection. I went through permissions, overrode the kernel to give me ownership of the device and still got the same error. Unless I was debugging, in which case access was fine.

The problem seemed to be that the device had not yet started up and putting a half second delay (you may have to increase it to find what works) was enough to allow the device to initialize and be accessed correctly. Try putting a short delay inside a finite loop while you try to open it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @mike. Unfortunately I have tried putting delays in a startup scripts, but even 10 or 15 seconds did not make any difference. To be honest I still don't know what was the reason here. On the other hand I have managed to get past the error with the use of `systemd` (I will write about it in a separate answer) but I still was forced to use 10 seconds delay in my client app as no communication packets where coming through my connection in the first few seconds (despite the fact that serial port has been opened successfully).